# What are domContentLoaded and domInteractive events?

Tags: javascript

I have read a lot of articles (also - articles at stackoverflow) avout the loading events - domContentLoaded and domInteractive, but I still do not have a clear understanding of it.

What means "interactive" in domInteractive and "content" in domContentLoaded?

Comment: I've never heard of a "dominteractive" event. There's a `domInteractive` property of the navigation timing API, is that what you mean?

Comment: yes. I meant domInteractive property

Comment: My answer earlier was confusing two separate things. You may find this page useful: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/measure-crp

Answer (score 2):

- 'interactive' is state when DOM is parsed ant ready as model, but CSS/images/JS still may be loading, therefore DOM is ready and user can interact with it. But note, there is no such 'domInteractive' event directly, you may seek him by the 'readystatechange' event. More: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange
- 'domContentLoaded' goes after document.readyState='interactive' and means same – DOM model is ready, but some resources may still be loading. When all resources are completely loaded, goes window 'load' event and 'readystatechange' with state 'complete'.